# RabbitMQ message signing

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I want to use RabbitMQ to communicate between multiple applications which are deployed on different networks and are maintained by different people. As a receiver of a message (consumer) I want to be convinced that the sender of the message (producer) is who he claims to be. Best approach I can think for this would be message signing and verification of those signatures. As this is my first time doing something with RabbitMQ, I am kind of stuck on how to implement this.

Message senders and receivers are Java applications. I've decided to use Spring AMQP template to make things somewhat easier for me. In a perfect scenario **I would like to somehow intercept the message when it's already a byte array/stream, sign this blob and attach the signature as a message header. On the receiving end I would again like to intercept the message before it's deserialized, verify the signature from header against the blob and if everything is OK then deserialize it.** But I havent found any means in Spring-Rabbit for doing this. 
There is a concept of `MessagePostProcessor` in Spring-Rabbit, but when this is invoked, the message is still not fully serialized. It seems like something that I imagined would be solved somewhere by someone as it feels like a common problem to have, but my research has left me bare handed.

Currently I am using `AmqpTemplate.convertAndSend` for message sending and `@RabbitListener` for message receiving. But I am not stuck with Spring. I can use whatever I like. It just seemed like an easy way to get going. I am using Jackson for message serialization to/from JSON. **Problem is how to intercept sending and receiving in the right place.**

Backup plan is to put both data and signature in body and joint them with a wrapper but this would mean double serialization and is not as clean as I would like the solution to be.

So has anyone got experience with this stuff and can perhaps can advise me on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a concept of `MessagePostProcessor` in Spring-Rabbit, but when this is invoked, the message is still not fully serialized.

I am not sure what you mean by that; the `MessagePostProcessor` is exactly what you need the `body` is the `byte[]` that will be sent to RabbitMQ. You can use an overloaded `convertAndSend` method that takes an MPP, or add your MPP to the template (in the `beforeSendMessagePostProcessors`).

On the receiving side, the listener container factory can be configured with `afterReceiveMessagePostProcessors`. Again; the `body` is the `byte[]` received from RabbitMQ.

Comment: You are correct. My bad. I did not examine the API thoroughly enough.